# how to get contours edge values in android opencv project

Tags: android, opencv

i am working on android project in opencv and my task is to crop the image where i touch that after finding contours i want to crop that only part.

the problem is that i already found the contours of image and i want to get coordinates of every contour of image that i can crop that particular part.

So, code is this:-

```
ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3;
Bitmap bmInImg, bmOutImg, bmImg;

private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
private static final int PIC_CROP = 1;
private boolean mIsColorSelected = false;
private Mat mRgba, tmp,tmp1;
private Scalar mBlobColorRgba;
private Scalar mBlobColorHsv;
private ColorBlobDetector mDetector;
private Mat mSpectrum;
private Size SPECTRUM_SIZE;
private Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i(TAG, "Trying to load OpenCV library");
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_5, this,
            mLoaderCallback)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
    }

    imageView1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    InputStream is;
    is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.mask);
    bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmInImg);

}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

        }
            break;
        default: {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
            break;
        }
    }
};

public native boolean CannyJNI(int width, int height, int[] mPhotoIntArray,
        int[] mCannyOutArray);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("first-opencvjni");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        tmp1 = new Mat(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(),
                CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmInImg, tmp1);

        tmp= new Mat();

        // 1) Apply gaussian blur to remove noise
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(tmp1, tmp, new Size(1, 1), 3);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);



        Imgproc.Canny(tmp, tmp, 10, 100);

        bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmOutImg);

        imageView3.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);

    //  Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);

        // 2) AdaptiveThreshold -> classify as either black or white
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(tmp, tmp, 255,
                Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 1);



        // 3) Invert the image -> so most of the image is black
        Core.bitwise_not(tmp, tmp);



        // 4) Dilate -> fill the image using the MORPH_DILATE

        Imgproc.dilate(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(1, 1)));



        //Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);


        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(tmp, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

          hierarchy.release();


         //  Imgproc.drawContours(tmp, contours, -1, new Scalar(Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255));
        tmp1.copyTo(tmp);

        Imgproc.drawContours(tmp, contours, -1, new Scalar(0,255,0), 1);

        bmImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmImg);
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

        int positionX = (int) event.getX();
        int positionY = (int) event.getY();

        Log.i("ON TOUCH COORDINATES", "x: " + positionX + " y: "
                + positionY);
        int color_selected = bmImg.getPixel(positionX, positionY);
        int redValue = Color.red(color_selected);
        int blueValue = Color.blue(color_selected);
        int greenValue = Color.green(color_selected);

        Log.i("COLOR SELECTED", " " + color_selected);
        Log.i("redValue", " " + redValue);
        Log.i("blueValue", " " + blueValue);
        Log.i("greenValue", " " + greenValue);  



    }
    return true;

}




private Scalar converScalarHsv2Rgba(Scalar mBlobColorHsv2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Mat pointMatRgba = new Mat();
    Mat pointMatHsv = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, mBlobColorHsv2);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(pointMatHsv, pointMatRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL,
            4);

    return new Scalar(pointMatRgba.get(0, 0));
}

void OutputBitmapToFile(Bitmap InBm, String Filename) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

    File f = new File(Filename);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        // write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

So, please help me out to get the coordinates of image after finding contours.

Thanks.

Comment: Contours are found on (Canny) edges. So, the results are what you are asking. Access your `List<MatOfPoint> contours`.

Comment: Hi, can we provide some code for this. i m new in this. so, didn't got any code regarding this.

Comment: Read [vector of vector](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21909/Introduction-to-dynamic-two-dimensional-arrays-in). Then, read [Basic structures](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html) to understand CvPoint. And how [cvDrawContour](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp?rev=4211) works as an example.

Comment: You can also simplify the contour to a polygon. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682840/opencv-detect-hand-drawing-shapes/16695591#16695591).

Comment: Hi, i want to crop image... i have found the contours of image and i want to crop the area of the particular contours where we click.