# Detecting shapes with opencv - android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and I need to develop an Shape detection android app
I need some tutorials explaining this filed

Answer (score 1):

I can always prefer to other stack overflow links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16695591/2356808

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11427501/2356808